# CTRL+ALT+DEL not working in win32api and python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywinauto

I am using python to virtually run the keyboard, using the following code for doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is not working, however, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or other key combinations are working this way.
The list of hex codes I am referring is from [here](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html)

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time

win32api.keybd_event(0xA2, 0,0,0)
time.sleep(.01)
win32api.keybd_event(0xA4, 0,0,0)
time.sleep(.01)
win32api.keybd_event(0x2E, 0,0,0)
time.sleep(.04)

win32api.keybd_event(0xA2,0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)
time.sleep(.01)
win32api.keybd_event(0xA4,0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)
time.sleep(.01)
win32api.keybd_event(0x2E,0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)
```

Help from anyone would be appreciated. Using windows 7 for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The [secure attention sequence (SAS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721625.aspx#_security_secure_attention_sequence_gly) cannot be produced by faking input. You need to call the [`SendSAS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761.aspx) function.

Note that the documentation for `SendSAS` lists some rather severe conditions for its use. You will need to adhere carefully to these conditions in order to succeed, and this might well prove very difficult for a Python program. It make be expedient to wrap the call to `SendSAS` in a separate executable.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting something similar, is there a way you can propose to do this through Pywinauto, or Pyautogui, or some other library, or by calling some core win api functions ?

Comment: If you read the required conditions in the linked documentation, as I mentioned, I think you will agree that they will be tricky to meet in a Python program.

Comment: A Python script can do this in one of two ways: (1) create a service using PyWin32 that runs as SYSTEM or (2) create a task (via COM or schtasks.exe) that runs as SYSTEM in the services session. As documented, you'll have to modify the group policy on the system to allow this. In either case the script can simply call `SendSAS(0)` via ctypes as soon as it starts (i.e. by starting the service via sc.exe, net.exe, or `win32service` or running the task via COM or schtasks.exe).

Comment: @eryksun Why don't you post it as an answer... It is a valid candidate.

Comment: My intent was to hint at what David means by "tricky", i.e. you can't simply call `SendSAS` from an arbitrary script. It has to be called in a particular context on a system that's been configured to allow it, either from a service running as SYSTEM or an application manifested with "uiAccess" that's signed by Authenticode.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is a reserved system function in Windows for all I know. This means that the operating system will not pass the command on to your program at all.

Someone correct me on this if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Yes, Mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841820/ctrlaltdel-not-working-in-win32api-and-python#answer-43842599